# R changing format of scale on y-axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot that has $-amounts and dates on y and x axis respectively.  Currently the dollar amounts range from $0-15 million.  Something like this:

```
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 1000000
plot(x)
```

R does stuff like `'1.0e+07'` instead of `'10,000,000'` and also orients the text vertically instead of horizontally.

My questions are:

1) how would I get the scale text to be horizontally oriented?

2) how would I get R to use `10MM` instead of `'10,000,000'` or `'1.0e+07'`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1) See the `scipen` option in `?options` which is a penalty against the use of scientific notation. For better control, you need to plot the axis by hand with labels you want.

2) See `las` in `?par` which controls to orientation crudely of axis labels.

For 1):

```
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 10000000
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(x)
getOption("scipen")
opt <- options("scipen" = 20)
getOption("scipen")
plot(x)
options(opt)
layout(1)
```

which gives

[image]

To plot your own axis try

```
plot(x / 10000000, axes = FALSE)
axis(1)
pts <- pretty(x / 10000000)
axis(2, at = pts, labels = paste(pts, "MM", sep = ""))
box()
```

Which gives

[image]

Where we use `pretty()` to select pretty locations for the ticks just as R would and then add a custom axis. Notice how we suppress axis drawing in the `plot()` call and then add back the axes and the plot frame with calls to `axis()` and `box()`.

For 2) combining with 1)

```
opt <- options("scipen" = 20)
op <- par(mar = c(5,7,4,2) + 0.1) ## extra margin to accommodate tick labs
x <- rnorm(20)^2 * 10000000
plot(x, las = 1, ylab = "")       ## no y-axis label 
title(ylab = "label", line = 5.5) ## need to plot the axis label
par(op)
options(opt)
```

Which gives

[image]

Notice how we use `las` in the `plot()` call, and we need to create some extra margin space to accommodate the tick labels. We also need to plot the label by hand otherwise R will stick it in amongst the tick labels.

For the custom axis labels, add the `las = 1` to the `axis()` call:

```
op <- par(mar = c(5,5,4,2) + 0.1)
plot(x / 10000000, axes = FALSE, ylab = "")
axis(1)
pts <- pretty(x / 10000000)
axis(2, at = pts, labels = paste(pts, "MM", sep = ""), las = 1)
title(ylab = "my label", line = 4)
box()
par(op)
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Use `axis` with custom labels. First, divide your data by 1 million. And then create a series with the MM notation using paste()

```
y <-rnorm(20)^2 * 1000000 /1000000
x <-11:30

plot(x,y, yaxt="n")
my.axis <-paste(axTicks(2),"MM",sep="")
axis(2,at=axTicks(2), labels=my.axis)
```

The text is now horizontal. But if you run into a problem use, las=1 to force labels to be horizontal.

```
axis(2,at=axTicks(2), labels=my.axis, las=1)
```

[image]