# Change x-axis in frequency plot

Tags: r, axis-labels, frequency-distribution

I wrote a short script to create a frequency distribution plot from raw data. The only thing I cannot make right is the x-axis. As you can see below, when the numbers are too long they got written in the e-notation which is difficult to read (also, labels are long enough to be cut out from the picture).

[image]

Normally I would use `digits = X` but unfortunately this notation cannot be used with the command `cut`. Full code is attached. Also, any other advice to make the graph more readable is warmly welcome.

```
##Paramaters definition
num.bins = 60 #The number of bins you want to be used
w.data = 2 #The column you have the data in

##Data loading
dataset = read.csv(file.choose())

##Calculating frequency
d.min = min(dataset[,w.data])
d.max = max(dataset[,w.data])

breaks = seq(d.min, d.max, by = (d.max-d.min)/num.bins)
d.cut = cut((dataset[,w.data]), breaks, right = FALSE, digits = 6)
d.freq = table(d.cut)

##Plot
plot(d.freq, ylab = 'Frequency', las = 2)
```

Comment: So the `cut` function has a `labels` argument that controls how the intervals are labelled. You haven't said how you'd like the intervals labelled or what you have attempted thus far using the `labels` argument.

Comment: Check the answers at this other thread: [R changing format of scale on y-axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918452/r-changing-format-of-scale-on-y-axis).

Answer (score 0):

Weird to answer to my own question; however, I found the solution.

The `cut` function has a `dig.lab` argument which is an equivalent of `digits`. Why two commands with the same function were implemented with different names is obscure to me.

So, the amended code looks something like:

```
##Paramaters definition
num.bins = 35 #The number of bins you want to be used
w.data = 2 #The column you have the data in

##Data loading
#dataset = read.csv(file.choose())

##Calculating frequency
d.min = min(dataset[,w.data])
d.max = max(dataset[,w.data])

breaks = seq(d.min, d.max, by = (d.max-d.min)/num.bins)
d.cut = cut((dataset[,w.data]), breaks, right = FALSE, dig.lab = 6)
d.freq = table(d.cut)

##Plot
par(mar=c(4,4.5,3,1))
par(oma=c(4,2,0,0) )
plot(d.freq, ylab = 'Frequency', las = 2)
mtext(side=3, text="Frequency Distribution", line=1.2, cex=1.5)
```

This results in:

[image]

Thank you very much to @joran and @celiomsj for pointing me in the right direction.